# Realtek ALC272 Mic not working on Lenovo S10-3

Tags: 12.04, alsa, realtek

`lspci` output

```
00:1b.0 Audio Device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rec 02)
```

when doing `alsactl init`, it shows ALC272

I've been using it since Ubuntu 11.04 and 11.10 and mic was working, but since the update to 12.04 the microphone problem appears.

I tried to compile the Realtek alsa-driver for hda-intel but still the same,

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article from an Ubuntu developer about fixing on-board and external audio issues.

http://voices.canonical.com/david.henningsson/